# Sketchflow Panorama in WPF Application

Tags: wpf, expression, sketchflow

When creating a Windows Phone 7 template I have Panorama and PanoramaItem controls. However when creating a new WPF application, I am missing these sets of controls. Is the panorama not compatible with WPF?

Is there currently a workaround? I have heard things about using a Horizontal WrapPanel but I would need some further instruction on this as I am new to Expression Blend 4.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: by expression, do you mean 'Expression Blend"?

Comment: yes, sorry i should have clarified that :)

Answer (score 0):

Panorama and PanoramaItem are Windows Phone controls, SL versions that simulate some of the functionality are included in the SketchFlow WP template, but they are not compatible with WPF.

Comment: Thanks Chuck, are there any other controls that might simulate this functionality within WPF?

Comment: I have worked around this using Sketchflow Animations which simulate the look and feel of the Panorama control, and triggering the playing of each animation with a mouse gesture or click event. If anybody needs instruction on this I will get back to you with more information.